# Having issue with z indexing Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working [on this demo code](https://www.bootply.com/BeiNDlyWmU). Why am I not able to put the `.dropdown-menu` behind the `.navbar-default`?

```css
.navbar-default {
  z-index: 2001;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 1001;
  top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: did you try it without the css .navbar-default {
  z-index: 2001;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 1001;
  top: 60%;
}

Comment: thanks for comment mkegg , but what do u mean?

Comment: In the code snippet that you shared, there seems to be no overlap

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `z-index` of `2001` on the a tag in the navigation, or you can put the `z-index` of `-1` on the `dropdown-menu` class.

Comment: your dropdown basicly have z-index of 1001 and the dropdown li actualy doesnt have the z-index. that why the dropdown isn;'t behind